# Is it possible to create a hadoop cluster by connecting three single node machines?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

If i have three three virtual machines with cloudera hadoop single node installed, is it possible to create a cluster by connecting three of them?
like one as namenode and other two as datanodes.

I am following [this](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/cdh_qs_cdh5_pseudo.html) documentaion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can connect them and things should be easy once all hosts run in pseudo-distributed mode ( all the demons on the same host ).
In theory all you have to do is configuration change on all 3 hosts.
In practice you have to read *also* [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html) because things are a bit different.

The first external datanode is hard work, any other will follow with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) tutorial provides exactly what you need. HTH.